# Angular 4 Formarray unique value validation for email

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

I am working in angular 4. I have created below formArray for creating multiple dynamic form.

```
this.addForm = FormBuilder.group({
    userRows: FormBuilder.array([])
});

addNewRow() {
    const control = <FormArray>this.addAdminForm.controls['userRows'];
    control.push(this.initAdminRows());
}   
initAdminRows() {      
    return this._fb.group({
        'userEmail': ['', Validators.required],
        'userName': ['', Validators.required],
    });
}
```

For example , If I add 2 forms and put same value for userEmail control. at that time I want to show error message and make my SAVE button disabled.

```html
<button (click)="addNewRow()">  ADD   </button>      
    <button (click)="saveData()" [disabled]="addForm .controls.userRows.invalid">
        Continue
    </button>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: your snippet is showing error

Comment: add your code in stackblitz.com

Comment: @Chellappan, not possible

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala, I have added more code